# MS Access property sheet error

Tags: ms-access, properties

I'm having some issues with the property sheets on both MSAccess 2003 and 2010 (I'm using both because our offices are transferring over to access 2010).

Problem : Whenever I want to edit any form, the property sheet displays fine but it won't allow me to select/edit any of the objects properties. I'm unable to even change tabs. Is there a fix?

Comment: Sounds like corruption... Have you tried to repair and compact? Have you tried importing all of your objects into a new (blank) database?

Comment: @CEXT: Please don't use backticks for anything but _code_, see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88)

Comment: how would I perform a repair and compact? The property sheet sometimes works fine, and then all of a sudden just freezes. Could this have something to do with the fact I use sql server management studio to work concurrently with my access database?